# How to set to user account value "must not enter a user and password to use this computer" through c# code

Tags: c#

How to set to user account value "must not enter a user and password to use this computer"
when power up the computer the user wouldn't have to insert his user name & password
 through c# code

Comment: Why would you want to sent this from code?  That seems like something that the user should consciously set, not accidentally do with a program.

Comment: This does not appear to be a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of doing this, and both ways are fairly insecure.

One way to do it would be to clear out the password for the user, in which case, if it is the only user account on the system in Windows XP or higher, it will automatically log itself in.

The other way to do it, is to create three registry entries under **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon**:

```
DefaultUserName (reg_sz): Set to the user's username
DefaultPassword (reg_sz): Set to the user's password
AutoAdminLogon (dword): Set to 1 to enable; 0 to disable
```

More information is available here:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315231

Please be aware that this information is visible in the registry to anyone who has the ability to run the registry editor, so make sure the password is not something used elsewhere, or that the workstation is secure from other users.

To set this value through code, you can do the following:

```
        RegistryKey winlogonKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software").OpenSubKey("Microsoft").OpenSubKey("Windows NT").OpenSubKey("CurrentVersion").OpenSubKey("WinLogon", true);
        winlogonKey.SetValue("DefaultUserName", "the_user's_username");
        winlogonKey.SetValue("DefaultPassword", "the_user's_password");
        winlogonKey.SetValue("AutoAdminLogon", 1);
```

Comment: the running failed on this line with NullReferenceException:
 RegistryKey winlogonKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software").OpenSubKey("Microsoft").OpenSubKey("Windows NT").OpenSubKey("CurrentVersion").OpenSubKey("WinLogon", true); 
what the problem?

Comment: You need to make sure to run this as Administrator, otherwise you will have problems accessing the key in read/write mode.

I just tested it myself and it works fine.

Comment: What values I should take? CurrentVersion? ...
Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what you mean when you say "what values should I take".

Everything I have written works properly.  Make sure you run it as Administrator (run Visual Studio in elevated mode to ensure you can debug it) and it will function.

Comment: this code works fine in my computer:
Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\...);